# iPhone app error when user comments: sslv3 alert certificate expired

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ssl

We just released a new version of our rails application and our iPhone app still works fine except when a user goes to comment on a post they get a 500 error. They can still make a post, but not comment.

We're getting this error

> "error = "SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A:
> sslv3 alert certificate expired";

What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The server administrator needs to replace the expired certificate(s) in the chain.
This may require getting renewed certificates from the Certificate Authority.